# Can ANT parametrize InnoSetup script?

Tags: ant, inno-setup, 32bit-64bit

The final step of building our java application (using ANT script) involves Inno Setup to package everything in a nice windows installer.

We are now upgrading our ANT script to generate both a 32-bit and a 64-bit version of our application. Our question is thus: how can we parametrize our Inno Setup config file so that it can generate both a x86 and a x64 version (it would thus be called 2x by the ANT script, with a parameter indicating the x86/x64).

In the Inno Setup config file, there is only 1 line that needs to be changed based on this parameter:

```
ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64
```

And this is how we call Inno Setup command line from ANT:

```
<exec executable="C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5\iscc.exe">
    <arg value="/cc" />
    <arg value="${dir.create_setup}/CreateSetup.iss" />
</exec>
```

Any help / hint on how to do this would be greatly appreciated !

Thanks,
Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [copy task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) with filtering, may be used for other dynamic values also.
your iss configfile template has :

```
ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=@32or64@
```

your build.xml has :

```
<filter token="32or64" value="${32or64}"/>
<copy file="foobar.iss" tofile="foobaz.iss" filtering="true" overwrite="true"/>

<exec executable="C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5\iscc.exe">
 <arg value="/cc" />
 <arg value="foobaz.iss" />
</exec>
```

then start your ant file with userproperty 32or64 like that :

```
ant -f build.xml -D32or64=x64
```

or

```
ant -f build.xml -D32or64=x86
```

copy task with filtering will replace the token @32or64@ with the value of userproperty 32or64, so foobaz.iss has either :

```
ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x64
```

or

```
ArchitecturesInstallIn64BitMode=x86
```